# what are outbound privileges in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In the snowflake [grant ownership documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/grant-ownership.html), there is a reference to "outgoing privileges."

What are "outgoing privileges?

This is part of the optional parameter "copy/revoke current grants."

It says, "Transfers ownership of an object along with a copy of any existing outbound privileges on the object."

I am trying to figure out what "outbound privileges" are.

**EDIT**:
Here is a test I ran.  I'm not seeing the difference.

```
create or replace view sandbox.test_schema.my_test_view
as
select 1 a;

grant ownership on view sandbox.test_schema.my_test_view to role ABC

show grants on view sandbox.test_schema.my_test_view
```

Privilege=ownership; granted_to=ROLE; grantee_name=ABC; grant_option=true; granted_by=ABC

if i add the copy grants

If instead I run everything exactly the same except I copy grant privileges

```
grant ownership on view sandbox.test_schema.my_test_view to role ABC copy current grants
```

The result of showing grants on the view are identical.

Is there an example where "copy current grants" makes a difference?

Comment: Updated my answer to cover your latest question.

Comment: Outgoing privilege is ANY privilege/grant on the object other than ownership (in case, you accept that being ownership is a privilege). For example, if you grant SELECT privilege explicitly to the role which owns the object, changing ownership will fail saying "Dependent grant exits".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Outbound privileges" mean existing privileges (current grants) on the object.

So you updated your sample and asked if there is an example where "copy current grants" makes a difference?

Assume that there's another role (DEF), and we granted select on the sample view:

```
create role DEF;
grant select on sandbox.test_schema.my_test_view to role DEF;
```

In this case, the following command would fail saying "SQL execution error: Dependent grant of privilege 'SELECT' on securable 'SANDBOX.TEST_SCHEMA.MY_TEST_VIEW' to role 'DEF' exists":

```
grant ownership on view sandbox.test_schema.my_test_view to role ABC;
```

To overcome this issue:

1) We can remove existing grants manually, and retry the first statement:

```
revoke select on sandbox.test_schema.my_test_view from role DEF;
grant ownership on view sandbox.test_schema.my_test_view to role ABC;
```

2) We can remove existing grants automatically:

```
grant ownership on view sandbox.test_schema.my_test_view to role ABC revoke current grants;
```

3) We can keep existing grants while changing the ownership:

```
grant ownership on view sandbox.test_schema.my_test_view to role ABC copy current grants;
```

So the "COPY/REVOKE current grants" make a difference if there are existing grants on the object.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  I just added an edit to my question with a test that I did, hoping to see a difference.  Do you have any documentation or perhaps an example to illustrate "outgoing privileges?"

Comment: Would you agree that "outgoing privileges" are privileges granted to roles other than object owner role?